# I want to validate date format is in YYYY-MM-DD and if user put in any other format it should be shown as error (Pandas)

Tags: pandas, date, validation, format

so i am reading csv file, in which dates are been mentioned

df = pd.read_excel(r'filepath, sheet_name='Sheet1',encoding='latin1',index=False)

when i print such column print (date)

0    2019-04-04
1    2020-03-06
2    2020-03-06
3    2020-03-17
4    2020-03-17
        ...
89   2020-03-18
90   2020-03-16
91   2020-03-20
92   2020-03-20
93   2020-03-20

Name: DocumentDate, Length: 94, dtype: datetime64[ns]

but such date is automatically change in YYYY-MM-DD format therefore i cannot identify whether used correct format or not however i need following output

1. 01-04-2019             **Incorrect Date format**
2. 2019-04-21               **Correct Date format**
3. 01.01.2019             **Incorrect Date format**

I tried to convert such column in object and string also but same provide me same answer, so how do i check such format so that i can provide output to the user that you have mentioned date in wrong format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show what you've tried up to now, where you have a problem and what is your question.

Comment: Please edit you question to include the information you gave in your comment, so it would be easier for people to help you. Do not forget to use correct formatting to increase readibility.

Comment: Looks like you are reading excel file, not csv file. More, there are no incorrect dates in the file  in your example. What happens if there is one ? I guess the print instruction is `print(df['date'])`, I am wrong ?